# Filter out whole div on the basis of inner elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

it's gonna be quite difficult for me to put everything here in short.
Assume all the classes are already styled in css.

I have several divs of same class like this:-

```html
<div id="s1" class="perschoolcontainer">
 <a href="abc.jpg" >
  <img id="dp1" class="dp" src="abc.jpg">
 </a>
 <p>Cricket</p>
</div>
<div id="s2" class="perschoolcontainer">
 <a href="def.jpg" >
  <img id="dp2" class="dp" src="def.jpg">
 </a>
 <p>Tennis</p>
</div>
<div id="s3" class="perschoolcontainer">
 <a href="ghi.jpg" >
  <img id="dp3" class="dp" src="ghi.jpg">
 </a>
 <p>Tennis</p>
</div>
```

they are the children of parent `div` with `id=show`

```html
<div id="show">
  <div id="s1" class="perschoolcontainer">
 <a href="abc.jpg" >
  <img id="dp1" class="dp" src="abc.jpg">
 </a>
 <p>Cricket</p>
  </div>
  <div id="s2" class="perschoolcontainer">
 <a href="def.jpg" >
  <img id="dp2" class="dp" src="def.jpg">
 </a>
 <p>Tennis</p>
  </div>
  <div id="s3" class="perschoolcontainer">
 <a href="ghi.jpg" >
  <img id="dp3" class="dp" src="ghi.jpg">
 </a>
 <p>Tennis</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

i want to hide those children of show who don't have Tennis in their `p`.
And this starts from a selection menu.

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>
 <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="Tennis" class="check">Tennis
    </label>
  </li>
  
  <li>
 <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="Cricket" class="check">Cricket
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now whichever option i select from these two options, the `.perschoolcontainer` `div` which doesn't have that selected option present into should get removed.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($('input.check').is(':checked')){
 var value = $.trim($(this).val());
 if(value !=   $trim($("#show").children(".perschoolcontainer").children("p").text())){
  $(this).parents("div").css("display","none");
 }
  }
});
```

What's wrong with the jquery function here.
It is basically supposed to collect the value which is selected. Then it traverses in `#show` and if the text is not equal to the value then the parent div of this element should be hidden.

Thnx in advance :)

Comment: 1. If you want to ask a complex question, have a minimal way to reproduce it. JSFiddle is quite common. 2. Have a description of _what_ is wrong. 3. Try debugging it first and _then_ ask if you get stuck. 4. That function is fired once on page load, hence it won't run if you are interacting with the page afterwards - is that your problem?

Comment: @Vld i have already trimmed my problem to this extent. I haven't used jsfiddle yet..but surely from next time i'll use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust your selector as well as use an event instead of just an `if` statement.

You also, need to utilize `jQuery`'s `.each()` function because there are multiple elements and you want to loop through them and then check the text in them. You can easily hook into the `<p>` tag with a simple selector instead of having to do `.children()`... etc.

```
$(document).on('change', 'input.check', function(){
    var $input = $(this);
    var checkboxValue = $input.val();

    $('#show .perschoolcontainer > p').each(function(){
        if($(this).text() == checkboxValue && $input.is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
        else if($(this).text() == checkboxValue && !$input.is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @SudhanshuSaini keep in mind with the answer you chose, that their selector `$('#show .perschoolcontainer p')` will select all children `p` elements in the `.perschoolcontainer` which may cause you some issues if there are other children elements further down the dom tree. You should increase the specificity of the selector to `> p` so that it only gets direct children.

Comment: i just realised this...actual code contains alot more than this and hence urs is tackeling that too.

Comment: This solution is very bad, using hardcoded string, and only works for Tennis not for Cricket

Comment: @Adjit this is teaching wrong practices, very quick answer with very weak solution.

Comment: @MaciejSikora matter of opinion. Your answer is even more wrong than mine. It uses a foolish combination of `jQuery` and vanilla JS and you alternate between the two. That is not useful for readability or portability. I have updated my answer to use the value of the checkbox to check for the text, therefore any checkbox with a value will do what the OP wants.

Comment: @Adjit this is your opinion, i have different. I think war is over.

Comment: @Adjit this function is not doing anything when the option is unchecked. It should make it as it was before checking this option. I think the outer if is needed to be clubbed with an else too. Can u please help me out there.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're checking to see if one of the inputs is checked **at the start** when what you really want is to hide the divs when the input is checked.

```js
$(function() {

  $(document).on('change', '.check', function() {
    var checkVal = $('.check:checked').val();
    $('#show .perschoolcontainer p').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text() == checkVal) {
        $(this).closest('.perschoolcontainer').hide();
      } else {
        $(this).closest('.perschoolcontainer').show();
      }
    });
  });
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="show">
  <div id="s1" class="perschoolcontainer">
 <a href="abc.jpg" >
  <img id="dp1" class="dp" src="abc.jpg">
 </a>
 <p>Cricket</p>
  </div>
  <div id="s2" class="perschoolcontainer">
 <a href="def.jpg" >
  <img id="dp2" class="dp" src="def.jpg">
 </a>
 <p>Tennis</p>
  </div>
  <div id="s3" class="perschoolcontainer">
 <a href="ghi.jpg" >
  <img id="dp3" class="dp" src="ghi.jpg">
 </a>
 <p>Tennis</p>
  </div>
</div>

<ul class="list">
  <li>
 <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="Tennis" class="check">Tennis
    </label>
  </li>
  
  <li>
 <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="Cricket" class="check">Cricket
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Exactly what i need. Thanku so much sir.

Comment: this is wrong answer if both checkbox will be checked it will be no value in $('.check:checked').val()

Answer (score 1):

Full solution, i added also check on checkbox change.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var inputs=$("input[type='checkbox']");
  var divs=$("div.perschoolcontainer");

  //function checks checkboxes and show only does divs with text containng with value from checkbox
  function checkInputs(){

    //hide all
    divs.hide();


    for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){

      if (inputs.eq(i).prop("checked")){
         //checkbox is checked
         var value = $.trim(inputs.eq(i).val());
         //show does with p and text in it
         divs.find("p:contains('"+value+"')").parent().show();
      }

    }

   }

 //after web starts check checkboxes
 checkInputs();


 inputs.on("change",function(){
     //on checkbox change
     checkInputs();
 });

});
```

Working code - https://plnkr.co/edit/h5IU1J7ErfYKrsAERSE7?p=preview

Comment: since i am new to jquery and javascript..i could not understand whole of ur code, but i am trying to go through each and every function..anyways thnx for your contribution :)